# group list by data in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have table

```
id   customer_name  country  pincode

1    Jhon             Mexico  12209 

2    Ryan             Mexico  12209 

3    Max              Sweden  12209 

4    Steve            Germany  12209
```

i want output like this:

> ```
> Mexico  
>         Jhon, Ryan
>
> Sweden 
>          Max
>
> Germany 
>
>          Steve
> ```

Home.ts

```
show(){
    db.executeSql('SELECT *  from  tbl_data where coutry=?',[data.rows.item(i).country])

            .then((data) => {
              if (data.rows.length > 0) {
                alert(data.rows.length);
                for (let j = 0; j < data.rows.length; j++) {
                  this.userdata.push({
                  country:data.rows.item(j).country,
                   customername:data.rows.item(j).customername,
                 })
                 }}}
```

how I can group by the data like this in  ionic v3

How to achieve this with Ionic v3? Any ideas?

Comment: From where you are getting this data ? And Share some code that you tried so far.

Comment: using sqllite query

Comment: db.executeSql('SELECT *  from  tbl_data where country=?',[data.rows.item(i).country])

Comment: Share your query, And code so that we know whats you are intended to do? Edit the question and share some code.

Comment: added..........................

Comment: Since I'm not familar with Ionic, I will post the base algorithm as a comment: You need a sorting algorithm, that poeple from the same country follows after each other. I'm not sure, if sqlite supports ``ORDER BY country``, if so, then use it. Otherwise use an string compare (``-1`` for less than, ``0`` equals, ``1`` greater than) function for sorting by yourself the entries. And you need to remember the last country given from last query result index in order to compare it with the current one (for country-wise splitting into the corresponding lines). That's it ;-)

Comment: do you know javascript ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you are trying to group it by Country so for that you can implement the following in `TS`,

```
var country = new Set(this.displayItems.map(item => item.country)); 
this.result = [];
country.forEach(getCountry => 
  this.result.push({
    country_name: getCountry, 
    values: this.displayItems.filter(i => i.country === getCountry)
  }
  ))
```

Here the `this.displayItems` is what your data from your service.

And HTML template can be like,

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      Country
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      Customer Name
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <hr>

  <ion-row *ngFor="let item of result">
    <ion-col>
      {{ item.country_name }}
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <span *ngFor="let value of item.values">
        {{ value.customer_name }} ,
      </span>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-grid>
```

And you can see your expected output here in Ionic way,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-25rq2n ..

Comment: @prabhakaran7, The data which you made in question was created as service and it returns observable and on subscribe the data will be fetched. Based on the data we are searching for unique country names then based on it we are pushing the data into the ```result``` array .. So result is the final output which needs to be iterable.. Based on country name there will be values array.. So here the values can be iterable and the customer name can be displayed based on the country..

Comment: If you want to know entire thing then you need to learn Javascript methods such as Set, Map, Filter.. If you understand these methods then only you will get idea how it is working.. So learn Javascript if you are working in Angular/Ionic..

Comment: values: this.displayItems.filter(i => i.country === getCountry)   #what is i here##################

what happens in this line 
could you plz explain

Comment: @prabhakaran7, As i said ```this.displayItems``` is the array of data which comes from API Service, you are going to filter it and the filter will return each object inside the array and each object is denoted by ```i```, so here ```i.country``` will give all the country name inside the array, Already using ```new Set``` we have took of unique country so this line is meant to match with the unique country name with the filtered country name and if the matching is found then lets push the other values into ```values:``` in ```result``` array...

Comment: The name which you have used may or may not be same in the solution, as there is no enough code from your end, i made it like this.. You need to check for names..

Comment: @prabhakaran7, Do you mean instead of country name, you want to group with pincode??

Comment: If that was the case then replace country name with pincode like https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-gcyyyy .

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-25rq2n?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts   

check this link

Comment: Okay got it, Whether the each place have unique pin_code? You have given same pincode for all the place..

Comment: Take a look at this link, https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tf1iyh .. I have created the JSON with each country name has unique pin_code, for data you can look at the json data https://api.myjson.com/bins/19anqt

Comment: @prabhakaran7, I have given twitter link in my profile page, you can message me there..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by `group by` query.

SQL :

```
SELECT country, customer_name 
FROM tbl_data 
GROUP BY country, customer_name
```

So the complete code will be :

```
 db.executeSql('SELECT country, customer_name FROM tbl_data GROUP BY country, customer_name'[]).then((data) => { })
```

Comment: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Customer_name' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: Edited try now.

Comment: how i can print those data as  i given output